# Non-EU citizen spouse rights

Tags: eu-spouses

I am a Canadian with French dual citizenship currently in Europe with my Venezuelan girlfriend who is traveling on a 90 day schengen visa and we have decided that we would like to get married and relocate to Spain (We started our relationship 3 years ago in Canada) Once we have our marriage certificate from Denmark can I bring her to Spain with me and can she stay and work or must she return to her home country first which is in turmoil now. I've noticed that there is a "Non EU citizen spouse law" however I'm not sure if she'll be allowed to stay with me and work once we've filed the paperwork in Spain for her residency.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

She doesn't have to get back to Venezuela so long as she does not over stay her visa. She will be able to stay in Spain if you are married. When you arrive in Spain, first you have to register yourself with the office. You must prove that you are able to support yourself and her.

- You have 6.000 euros ( *in case you don't have a job* )
- You are registered in Spain ( *Empadronamiento* )
- You have a private insurance in Spain

Once you have registered yourself with the foreign office, she can apply for [Residence Card of a Family Member of a Union Citizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence_card_of_a_family_member_of_a_Union_citizen).

You must make an appointment for her through the page of [Ministerio de Hacienda y Administraciones Públicas](https://sede.administracionespublicas.gob.es/pagina/index/directorio/icpplus).

Once everything is done she would be able to work and live with you. The card issued is valid for 5 years.

P.S : If you intend to come Spain to live I strongly recommend you to make your appointments and collect all the necessary documents beforehand. It can be painful and time consuming otherwise.

Comment: "so long as she does not over stay her visa": Once they are married, her visa becomes irrelevant as she is a "person enjoying freedom of movement" under EU law (as long as she is with her spouse). She has to aply for the residence card within 90 days of arriving in Spain; earlier presence in other Schengen countries does not affect that. Otherwise a great answer, and welcome to the site.